# Can't justify content between in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, justify

I want to create add a nav in my html file and have tried using Bootstrap for the navbar. But I can't justify the content to add space between my links. I have found an example that would do that for me, but when I add the code to my html file, it acts really strange and the nav is not working!

This is the link that shows the navbar with justify-content-between: https://www.codeply.com/p/T2PwT6z0Bn

This is my code that is not working properly. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>News</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
                <div class="container">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar10">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <span class="navbar-brand hidden-lg-up">Brand</span>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100 align-items-start">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Justi</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Fied</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item hidden-md-down">
                                <h5 class="my-0"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Brand</a></h5>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bar</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <br>
                <h5>Nav fill example</h5>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#subscribed" data-toggle="tab">Mes inscriptions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventPassed" data-toggle="tab">Événements passés</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventNow" data-toggle="tab">Événements en cours</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventIncoming" data-toggle="tab">Événements futurs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventCreation" data-toggle="tab">Créer un événement</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventOwn" data-toggle="tab">Mes événements</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br>
                <h5>Nav justified example</h5>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#subscribed" data-toggle="tab">Mes inscriptions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventPassed" data-toggle="tab">Événements passés</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventNow" data-toggle="tab">Événements en cours</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventIncoming" data-toggle="tab">Événements futurs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventCreation" data-toggle="tab">Créer un événement</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventOwn" data-toggle="tab">Mes événements</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The proper output should look like this (Notice the black background with the nav links): [image]

But what I get when viewing in Chrome (There is no black background and the Brand is far in the end): [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the version used in the example you have. By looking at it I noticed it is using Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6 and you are using 4.4.1, so there is a chance that the visual aspect or functionality was changed.

In summary, you can have this to work with 4.4.1: [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>News</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse nav nav-pills nav-justified">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you can replace your stylesheet and js to match the version of the example and it will be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>News</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
                <div class="container">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar10">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <span class="navbar-brand hidden-lg-up">Brand</span>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100 align-items-start">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Justi</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Fied</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item hidden-md-down">
                                <h5 class="my-0"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Brand</a></h5>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bar</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <br>
                <h5>Nav fill example</h5>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#subscribed" data-toggle="tab">Mes inscriptions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventPassed" data-toggle="tab">Événements passés</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventNow" data-toggle="tab">Événements en cours</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventIncoming" data-toggle="tab">Événements futurs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventCreation" data-toggle="tab">Créer un événement</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventOwn" data-toggle="tab">Mes événements</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br>
                <h5>Nav justified example</h5>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#subscribed" data-toggle="tab">Mes inscriptions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventPassed" data-toggle="tab">Événements passés</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventNow" data-toggle="tab">Événements en cours</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventIncoming" data-toggle="tab">Événements futurs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventCreation" data-toggle="tab">Créer un événement</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#eventOwn" data-toggle="tab">Mes événements</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>          
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope that helps! :)